# Why does Entity Framework sometimes create relationships automatically and sometimes doesnt?

Tags: entity-framework

I have a simple schema similar to this:

> **Customer**
>
> CustomerId, FirstName, LastName, CreateDt
>
> **CustomerFeedback**
>
> CustomerFeedbackId, CustomerId, Feedback

There is a foreign key relationship between the two.

- I create a **LINQ to SQL** model from this, and a relationship line is drawn between the two tables.
- I create an **Entity Framework** model from this, and no relationship is drawn between the tables.

I've created other schemas and the relationships are automatically drawn. I can't see why it's not working here. My schema is more complicated than this, but I'm only trying to add these two tables. There is definitely a foreign key established because when I create a database diagram in enterprise manager and add the tables the relationship is shown.

How does EF decide when to automatically create relationships?

I can manually create it, but i really hate doing that in case I mess it up. I've restarted Visual studio and started from a completely empty model and it's still doing it.

Comment: Is there perhaps a document somewhere explaining rules on how relationships and created?

Comment: Show your full metadata, including table definitions and FKs.

Comment: @craig stuntz - i removed all other relationships to customer (customer 1-* order) and created a completely new database with just Customer and CustomerFeedback. the designer worked fine. so its not just the definitions - something really screwy is going on. i've renamed columns and verified they're being seen, i've removed all other FK relationships, verified keys etc., created brand new VS project and still nothing. i think i'm going to have to create it manually and move on :-/

Answer (score 0):

Shot in the dark, but is CustomerFeedback.CustomerId nullable and/or unique (via key)? I've seen the designer act a bit strange in scenarios like that, moreso the nullable FK one than the unique key one.

Comment: Pretty sure its not nullable, definitely not unique. Got frustrated and moved to the gym. Wouldn't the fact that it let me manually create the relationship suggest everything is ok?

Comment: CustomerId is not nullable in either table, and the identity column for 'Customer'. And like i said LINQ's designer DOES create a relationship, but entity framework doesnt...

Comment: Hard to say without seeing your metadata and t-sql. You mentioned enterprise manager which is a sql 2000 tool, are you using Sql Server 2000? If so, it would be interesting to see if you get the same experience using something like the express versions of 2005 or 2008.

Comment: faux pas - i'm on 2008. i'm giving up on this for now. something bizarre is happening and i need to move on. (see comment to craig above)

Answer (score 0):

In the end I just had to do this :

- Close all management studio designers for tables and diagrams
- `SELECT * INTO Customer2 from Customer`
- Recreate indexes and keys on `Customer2`
- Rename `Customer` > `CustomerOld`
- Rename `Customer2` > `Customer`

Now it works :-)
No schema change or any other change. 
I'd previously tried deleting and recreating FKs.
The *only* thing that wasn't respecting them was the EF designer so I don't know what was going on.